# How to unload and load json arrays in Galleria to switch gallery content?

Tags: jquery, json, carousel, galleria

I am trying to build a page with the ability to switch between different sets of images as my gallery content. I set up an experiment to try and get it to switch between two different sets of images like this:

```
<div id="galleria"></div>
<div class="under-galleria">
     <a href=# id="g-play-pause">Play/Pause</a>
     <a href=# id="switch">SWITCH</a>
</div>

<script>    
//content
var data = [
{
    thumb: 'img/thumb.1.jpg',
    image: 'img/med.1.jpg',
    big: 'img/lrg.1.jpg',
},
                                    {
    thumb: 'img/thumb.2.jpg',
    image: 'img/med.2.jpg',
    big: 'img/lrg.2.jpg',
},

];
var data2 = [
{
    thumb: 'img/thumb.3.jpg',
    image: 'img/med.3.jpg',
    big: 'img/lrg.3.jpg',
},
                                    {
    thumb: 'img/thumb.4.jpg',
    image: 'img/med.4.jpg',
    big: 'img/lrg.4.jpg',
},
];                          

//left and right arrows control from keyboard
Galleria.ready(function() {
var gallery = this; 
 gallery.attachKeyboard({
        left: gallery.prev,
        right: gallery.next,
    });
 });

 //load theme                                                               
 Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');

 //configure
Galleria.configure({
    thumbnails:'lazy',
    lightbox: true,
    dataSource:data
});
//on ready functions (lazy load, auto play)
Galleria.ready(function(){
    this.lazyLoadChunks(3);
    this.play(3000);
});

 //run and extend
 Galleria.run('#galleria', {
//play/pause toggle
    extend: function() {
        var gallery = this; 
        $('#g-play-pause').click(function() {
            gallery.playToggle()
        }); 
        $('#switch').click(function() {
            gallery.destroy({dataSource:data})
            gallery.load({dataSource:data2})
        }); 
    }
}); 

</script>
```

This loads the first set of images "data" but when I click the switch link it only removes the first set, but does not add the second set ("data2"). There are no console errors, just a sad, empty galleria. I tried using splice, and push, but that didn't work either...

What I want to happen is for Galleria to load images 1 and 2 (data) and when I click the #switch link remove images one and two and replace them with images 3 and 4 (data2). Eventually i'd like to be able to combine them, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#switch').click(function() {
    gallery.load(data2);
});
```

EDIT:
You need to call `lazyLoadChunks` after data change. Small timeout needed.

```
$('#switch').click(function() {
    gallery.load(data2);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        gallery.lazyLoadChunks(3);
    },10);
});
```

Or you can listen to `data` event

```
Galleria.ready(function(){
    var gallery = this;
    $('#switch').click(function() {
        gallery.load(data2);
    });
}); 
Galleria.on('data',function(){
    var gallery = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        gallery.lazyLoadChunks(3);
    },10);
});
```

Comment: That works. Not sure how I missed that option... Thanks. It didn't remove thumbnails. I tried adding gallery.lazyLoad(data2) which didn't work. Disabling lazy loading of thumbnails did solve the problem, but that is not ideal.

Comment: You need to call lazyLoadChunks after getting new data. Ill update answer.

Comment: Brilliant. That totally works, but what if I wanted it to load both of the arrays on page load? Sorry for being so javascript illiterate. I promise my copy of Javascript: The Definitive Guide is somewhere between here and Amazon.com. It really is, I ordered it yesterday:)

Comment: You are probably looking for [.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Why, yes that is what I was looking for.